# Laravel : QueryException in Connection.php line 770:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want create api with laravel put when test my url in postman i have error  this is my database [image]

the error :

> QueryException in Connection.php line 770: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table
>   or view not found: 1146 Table 'new_database.accounts' doesn't exist
>   (SQL: insert into `accounts` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (ammar, 2017-02-09 13:59:24, 2017-02-09 13:59:24))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is `account` and Laravel want to insert into table `accounts` (plural).

2 things to do to solve this problem

- rename your table from `account` into `accounts`

or

- add in your model `protected $table = 'account';`

Answer (score 1):

In screenshot **"new_database.acount"** in errors **"new_database.accounts**", check your query

Answer (score 0):

Your table name is **account**  and you are referring it with **accounts**. Change this and try again.